# Find a specific observable inside a list of observable's - Angular

Tags: angular

I've a list of observable's that i'm pushing to that list observable's according to some condition.
I have a requirement that I have to find one of the observables inside that list.

One of the approaches that I was thinking is:
When pushing those observables to the list add some extra property for the id.

Any help with how can  make it work would be appreciated?

**Example**:

```
private obsList: Observable<any>[] = []

private pushObsToList(obs: Observable<any>, status: boolean, obsId: any) {
   if (status) {
    this.obsList.push(obs)
}

private findObs(id: any) {
  ...how to find it?
}
}
```

- The list should remain of observables only.

Comment: Where does this id come from? Do you know the id when you push the Observable onto the array? How do you know the id when you want to find the observable? Does the order of the observables matter that are in the list?

Comment: @AaronHinni Thank you for the replay.
Yes, I know the id when I push the Observable.
I know the id from some other property.
The order of the list doesn't matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be easier to use a map or object instead of a list.

```
private pushObservable(obs: Observable<any>, id: any, status: boolean) {
  if (status) {
    this.obsMap[id] = obs;
  }
}

private findObs(id: any) {
  return this.obsMap[id];
}
```

And however you were using the list before...

```
Object.values(this.obsMap); // This will give you the array of observables, but order isn't guaranteed
```

Answer (score 0):

**Object/Interface:**

```
export class ObservableUnit {
  public obs: Observable<any>;
  public id: number;
}
```

**Implementation:**

```
private obsList: ObservableUnit[] = [];
private id: number = 1;
    
private pushObsToList(obs: Observable<any>, status: boolean) {
    if (status) {
        this.obsList.push({ obs: obs, id: this.id});
        this.id++;
    }
}
    
private findObs(id: number) {
    return this.obsList.filter(f => f.id === id)[0].obs;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the list should be a list of Observable's only